# selenium/chromedriver not completing file download

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

selenium/chromedriver is not completing to download a file, like a pdf, and leaving behind a `crdownload` file. This doesn't always happen, and while I realize waiting until verifying the file exists in the filesystem is the best way to do this, I'm curious if anyone could explain why this happens.

I am using `Network.loadingFinished` from the performance logs to determine when it's safe to close the driver session, but this still isn't always sufficient to determine that a file has finished downloading.

Comment: Maybe the antivirus is taking over and renaming it while it scans, it has happened to me a few times. Alternatively perhaps the file is so large the download is happening in chunks and once finished... technically there is nothing left on the network side but has yet to assemble into a single downloaded file?

Comment: antivirus is definitely something I was considering. These files are very small. The software in question is only having this problem on one particular user's host...not one I have control over.